# Why does .sav file become ten times bigger after adding a column in jupyter notebook using python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spss, filesize

I'm working with a .sav (SPSS) file in Jupyter Notebook. When I import the file it is 20MB. But after adding a single column to the file and exporting it as a .sav file using pyreadstat it is over 200MB. The data visualization software that I'm using only allows for max 200MB files so I have to get past this. Does anyone have experience with pyreadstat and knows how to get past this?
https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat

My guess is the size of the two dictionaries that define the variable value labels and the missing ranges causes the file size difference.

I don't know of another way to add new variables into the metadata than to create a dictionary from the metadata (I print the metadata and then copy and paste the output and save it as a dictionary) and assign it as the variable_value_labels in the export.

```
# This is my code to export the .sav file along with the variable value labels and missing ranges:
    pyreadstat.write_sav(df, "filename.sav", missing_ranges=missing_ranges_dict, variable_value_labels = metadata_dict )
```

The .sav file after the export works fine it's just too large

Comment: The dictionaries don't seem to be the problem. I tried exporting just the dataframe without any metadata and the only difference is is that it's 1MB less than if I export with the metadata

Comment: Have you tried using compression? compress=True will write a .zsav file which, in my experience, will cut the filesize in half at least.

Comment: I tried but it makes no difference. Am I using it correctly?
`pyreadstat.write_sav(c, "filename.sav", missing_ranges=missing_ranges, variable_value_labels = meta_dict, compress = True )`

Comment: I guess you are. Is the .sav file in Unicode mode? SPSS has this annoying thing of tripling of string field widths when converting from Codepage to Unicode, So you might have blown up strings in you data. Try saving the original data in Unicode within SPSS and watch what happens.

Comment: Great thank you! That worked. Now the exported file is even smaller than the imported one :)